# longtable formatting issue. How to remove extra vertical dashes on the side when table cross page

Tags: longtable

When I run this MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pifont} %http : // ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\textcolor{blue}{\Large \ding{51}}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\textcolor{red}{\Large \ding{55}}}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1.2in,footskip=.7in,headsep=.5in]{geometry}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{.25in}|p{1in}|p{2in}|p{0.525in}|p{0.3in}|p{0.525in}|p{0.3in}|p{.32in}|p{.32in}|}
\caption{Miscellaneous PDE's breakdown of results. Time in seconds}\\\hline
\#&PDE&description&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Mathematica}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Maple}&\footnotesize{hand solved?}&\footnotesize{animated?}\\ \cline{4-7}
&&&result&time&result&time&&\\\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{9}{|c|}{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- Miscellaneous PDE's. Continued from previous page}\\\hline 
\#&PDE&description&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Mathematica}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Maple}&\footnotesize{hand solved?}&\footnotesize{animated?}\\ \cline{4-7} 
&&&result&time&result&time&& 
\endhead \hline 
\multicolumn{9}{|r|}{Continued on next page} \\\hline 
\endfoot \hline 
\endlastfoot
1&A&Transport equation $u_t+ u_x = 0$&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.041&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.014&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{}\\ \hline
2&A&Transport equation $u_t-3 u_x = 0$ IC $u(0,x)=e^{-x^2}$. Peter Olver textbook, 2.2.2 (a) &\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.005&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.061&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}\\ \hline
3&A&Transport equation $u_t+2 u_x = 0$ IC $u(-1,x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$. Peter Olver textbook, 2.2.2 (b) &\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.006&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.023&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}\\ \hline
4&A&Transport equation $u_t+u_x+\frac{1}{2}u = 0$ IC $u(0,x)=\arctan(x)$. Peter Olver textbook, 2.2.2 (c) &\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.004&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.047&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}\\ \hline
5&A&Transport equation $u_t-4u_x+u = 0$ IC $u(0,x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Peter Olver textbook, 2.2.2 (d) &\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.005&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.023&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}\\ \hline
6&A&Transport equation $u_t+2 u_x= \sin x$ IC $u(0,x)=\sin x$. Peter Olver textbook, 2.2.5&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.058&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.052&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}\\ \hline
7&A&Transport equation $u_t+\frac{1}{1+x^2} u_x= 0$ IC $u(x,0)=\frac{1}{1+(3+x)^2}$. Peter Olver textbook, page 27&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.018&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.157&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}\\ \hline
8&A&Transport equation $u_t-x u_x= 0$ IC $u(x,0)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Peter Olver textbook, problem 2.2.17&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.005&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.107&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}\\ \hline
9&A&Transport equation $u_t+(1-2 t) u_x= 0$ IC $u(x,0)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Peter Olver textbook, problem 2.2.29&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.07&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.213&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}\\ \hline
10&A&Transport equation $u_t+\frac{1}{x^2+4} u_x= 0$ IC $u(x,0)=e^{x^3+12 x}$&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.015&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.085&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}\\ \hline
11&A&$3 u_x + 5 u_y = x$&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.006&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.012&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{}\\ \hline
12&A&$x u_y + y u_x = -4 x y u$ and $u(x,0)=e^{-x^2}$&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.023&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.155&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{}\\ \hline
13&A&$u_t + u_x = 0$ and $u(x,0)=\sin x$ and $u(0,t)=0$&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.104&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.374&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{}\\ \hline
14&A&$u_t+ c u_x = 0$ and $u(x,0)=e^{-x^2}$&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.005&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.026&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{}\\ \hline
15&A&(Haberman 12.2.2) $\omega_t -3 \omega_x = 0$ and $\omega(x,0)=\cos x$&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.004&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.021&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{}\\ \hline
16&A&(Haberman 12.2.4) $\omega_t +c \omega_x = 0$ and $\omega(x,0)=f(x)$ and $\omega(0,t)=h(t)$&\textcolor{red}{\Large \xmark}&1.669&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}\newline Solution contains unresolved invlaplace calls&0.432&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{}\\ \hline
17&A&(Haberman 12.2.5 (a)) $\omega_t +c \omega_x = e^{2 x}$ and $\omega(x,0)=f(x)$&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.042&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.086&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{}\\ \hline
18&A&(Haberman 12.2.5 (d)) $\omega_t +3 t \omega_x = \omega(x,t)$ and $\omega(x,0)=f(x)$&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.396&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.096&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{}\\ \hline
19&A&$ 2 u_x + 5 u_y = u^2(x,y) + 1$&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.138&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&0.038&\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Yes}}&\footnotesize{}\\ \hline
142&A&Using integral transforms. &\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&39.73&\textcolor{blue}{\Large \cmark}&2.523&\footnotesize{}&\footnotesize{}\\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Using lualatex, it gives this PDF

[image]

I tried many variations and can't figure how to get rid of these extra `|` which show up whenever the table moves to new page.

TL 2023 on Linux.

Comment: Off-topic: Based on the code you provided, the table's width exceeds `\textwidth` by a considerable margin. To alleviate the situation a bit, you may wish to replace the `p`-type column specs of the first two columns with just `l`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `endhead` portion, you need to change

```
\multicolumn{9}{|c|}{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- ...
```

to

```
\multicolumn{9}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- ...
```